# What is the meaning of _bstr_t::operator=?

Tags: c++, com

I have some source code with COM string manipulation but have this code is make me confused

```
_bstr_t btLeft;
_bstr_t tempData ;
_bstr_t btRight ;
//Do something to assign values to 3 above variables 
.....
//And here
_bstr_t::operator = (btLeft + tempData + btRight); //confused!!!

return true
```

=> What is the meaning of this code?

```
_bstr_t::operator = (btLeft + tempData + btRight);
```

it's look like string concanate? which is returned value?

Comment: What is this? It's not a function declaration, because it lacks a return type and it's not a static function call, since operators can't be static functions. I am confused, is `_bstr_t::operator = (btLeft + tempData + btRight); valid c++?`

Comment: @churill this is a part of a function

Comment: My crystal ball says that you found this in a class that derives from `_bstr_t`.  In which case invoking the assignment operator is sensible to assign the private `_bstr_t::m_wstr` member.

Comment: This way it makes sense @HansPassant, thanks.
Then the answer to this question should be easy.

Answer (score 1):

It's the same as the following:

```
const auto foo = btLeft + tempData + btRight;
this->_bstr_t::operator=(foo);
```

1. `btLeft + tempData + btRight` adds together the three instances of `_bstr_t` ([see the documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/cpp/cpp/bstr-t-operator-add-equal-plus?view=vs-2019)). This does indeed concatenate the 3 strings.
2. `this->_bstr_t::operator=(foo);` takes the result of 1 and invokes the assignment operator ([see also the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/cpp/cpp/bstr-t-operator-equal?view=vs-2019)) of the base class which must be `_bstr_t`.

You could say it concatenates three strings and assigns the result to itself.

(All of this is under the assumption that Hasn Passant's crystal ball told him correctly, that your code is part of a member function of a class that inherits from `_bstr_t`)